# Create user with encrypted password with db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making my first app with rails and this app would be accessible only if user are logged and only admin can create user, so when my app would be online I need at least one admin to create the other right ?

I tried with seed to create an user, the user is well created but I can't connect to my app with it, I think it's a prob with the encrypted password, here is what I have done :

```
UserManager::User.create({ name: 'a', surname: 'a', email: 'a', active: true, id: 1, password_hash: 'a', password_salt: 'a'})
```

Is that possible and it is right to create user with seed ? and if it is how can I do to encrypt the password in seed ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making my first app with rails and this app would be accessible only if user are logged and only admin can create user, so when my app would be online I need at least one admin to create the other right ? **Yes**

Is that possible and it is right to create user with seed ? **This is probably a debatable point, but as long as you secure your seed file, it may be a reasonable approach.  You probably want to change the password as soon as possible and/or use an environment variable for your password.  Whatever you do, don't use plaintext, add your admin password to your git repository and then leave it unchanged in production.**

and if it is how can I do to encrypt the password in seed ? **You probably shouldn't be loading attributes like `password_hash` and `password_salt` explicitly.  Instead, just set `password` (and `password_confirmation` if you have it).**

Comment: I've an issue when I want to set 'password' and 'password_confirmation', these 2 fields are not in the database, they are just encrypted before save, so password is unknow, any idea ?

Comment: Yes you need `has_secure_password` in your model as documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).  You'll also need the `bcrypt` gem, which you should be using to generate a hash digest of the user's plaintext password.

Comment: I created a question more specific http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026248/encrypt-users-password-in-seed-file the problem is when I want to set password in the seed file, 'password' is unknown

Answer (score 0):

You should be Running:

```
UserManager::User.create(name: 'a', surname: 'a', email: 'a', password: 'foobar123', password_confirmation: 'foobar123')
```

Other answer by Steve answers the remaining issues.