# Encrypt User's password in seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I need to seed an user with encrypted password and I'm not using Devise. So I tried this :

```
user = UserManager::User.new({ :name => 'a', :surname => 'a', :email => 'a', :active => true, :password_hash => 'password', :password_salt => 'password'})
user.save
```

But this is not right to put password_hash and password_salt like this and I found that I have to put password and password_confirmation instead

```
user = UserManager::User.new({ :name => 'a', :surname => 'a', :email => 'a', :active => true, :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'})
user.save
```

But these 2 fields are unknow because they are not in the database, so how can I do to encrypt the password with seed ?

**EDIT**

**User model**

```
attr_accessor :password
has_secure_password
before_save :encrypt_password

def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the attribute accessor for `password`.  You get that for free when you use `has_secure_password`.

To seed users, I would recommend using Hartl's approach from his tutorial.

**User model**

Add a method for generating the password digest manually:

```
# Returns the hash digest of the given string.
def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end
```

**Seed file**

```
User.create!(name: 'foo',
             email: 'foo@bar.com',
             password_digest: #{User.digest('foobar')} )
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this. Should I add password_digest to my database ?

Comment: Yes @Simon.  This will be the hashed version of your user's plaintext password and should be the only password related data in your database.

Comment: Actually, I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1 for my authentication and I already have password_hash and password_salt in my database, so I don't think that add password_digest in my db would be right

Comment: Hmm that Railscast refers to a password_digest attribute at least in the ASCII cast.  Perhaps you can use password_hash in its place if you have gone in that direction.  You'll want some sort of helper method to invoke the `BCrypt` password method in your seed file.

Comment: Oops, wrong link sorry, this one : http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch ... Yes I think this is the best solution to use BCrypt in a method in seed file, but I'm new to rails and really don't know how to do this

Comment: I think that episode is obsolete - it does not appear to use `has_secure_password` which is the standard (and easiest) approach.

Comment: Then you recommend to me to do not use this approach and use has_secure_password ?

Comment: I really do Simon although I am not sure how far along you are.  If you already have a production app and are modifying, it may not be the right approach.

Comment: I have almost finish my app and it will be soon in production, I think then that is worth to use has_secure_password approach

Comment: OK GL @Simon.  Let us know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: I'll do my best, thank you Steve, I appreciate your help

Comment: Sure @Simon.  Besides the code fragments in my answer, you should just need `has_secure_password` and attribute `password_digest`, plus the `BCrypt` gem.  Should be pretty close to working at that point (`has_secure_password` is very magic, even for Rails).

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
end
```

In the seeds.rb file:

```
User.create(username: "username", 
     ...
password_digest: BCrypt::Password.create('Your_Password'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash of password something like following:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
encrypted_password= Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
```

You can use this code in your seeds.rb file to encrypt the password. But it seems that you have already written a method `encrypt_password`. Now, you can call this method in `before_save` callback. So each time, a user is about to be saved in database, `encrypt_password` will be called.

Comment: I'm using BCrypt to encrypt my password is that change something ?
Where should I put this code ? One of my problem is that I'm not able to use 'password' in the seed file

Comment: I've updated my User model. I already had a before_save callback. My problem appear when I want to seed the user, 'password' attribute isn't recognized