# Why am I receiving this error multiple times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-cloud9

I'm running a **$rails test** command to see if everything is alright, but I receive this:

```
ERROR["test_email_addresses_should_be_unique", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f2670deadd0 @name="UserTest">, 0.01948296799992022]
 test_email_addresses_should_be_unique#UserTest (0.02s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_password_should_be_present_(nonblank)", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005586062f6a20 @name="UserTest">, 0.039645324000048277]
 test_password_should_be_present_(nonblank)#UserTest (0.04s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_password_should_have_a_minimum_length", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000558606331508 @name="UserTest">, 0.05958008599986897]
 test_password_should_have_a_minimum_length#UserTest (0.06s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000558606364958 @name="UserTest">, 0.07700808699996742]
 test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses#UserTest (0.08s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f2670e5ea50 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.11646463199986101]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (0.12s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f2670eae8e8 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.12786450899989177]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.13s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005586063af020 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.14731222199998228]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.15s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_get_new", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f2670f26ac8 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.16310770199993385]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (0.16s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005586063c6478 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.17951116699987324]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.18s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_followers_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x000055860646fd70 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.1943119969998861]
 test_should_redirect_followers_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.19s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005586065155e0 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.21003705899988745]
 test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.21s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005586065cc038 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.2277173119998679]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (0.23s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_non-admin", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f2670f73760 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.24164153399988209]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_non-admin#UsersControllerTest (0.24s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_following_when_not_logged_in", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f2670fbf5e8 @name="UsersControllerTest">, 0.25870832299983704]
 test_should_redirect_following_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (0.26s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_get_contact", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f267100acc8 @name="StaticPagesControllerTest">, 0.2745016510000369]
 test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.27s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_get_home", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000558606717348 @name="StaticPagesControllerTest">, 0.2904469089999111]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.29s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_get_about", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00005586067deee8 @name="StaticPagesControllerTest">, 0.3036177300000418]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.30s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_should_get_help", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f26701107b8 @name="StaticPagesControllerTest">, 0.34408128299992313]
 test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.34s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

ERROR["test_layout_links", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f26701da1d0 @name="SiteLayoutTest">, 0.35210771399988516]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (0.35s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for #<Class:0x00007f2670dcdca8>
            test/fixtures/users.yml:4:in `get_binding'

  19/19: [==============================================================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.35965s
19 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 19 errors, 0 skips
ubuntu:~/environment/sample_app (master) $
```

This is what my users.yml file looks like. The error seems to be pointing in the exact same line. Apologies if this is glaringly obvious, I'm merely following a tutorial and have never touched Rails before.

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

malory:
  name: Malory Archer
  email: boss@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
<% end %>
```

this is line 4 ( what does 'get_binding' mean? )

```
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

**UPDATE** here is my user.rb file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User model in `app/models/user.rb` Is expected to have a `digest` method but doesn’t.

Your user `has_secure_password` which adds some extra methods to the user. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html for the docs. But not `User.digest`

Perhaps there is a part in the tutorial where you’ve skipped the creation of that method? Or maybe the tutorial is wrong or out of date.

Either way, in your users.yml file you can use `password_digest: BCrypt::Password.create('Your_Password'))` to set a password for each user instead of the User.digest method.

See [Encrypt User's password in seed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026248/encrypt-users-password-in-seed-file) for someone with the same root problem.